# Selenium doesn't open firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara, webrat

When I run a test using cucumber and selenium, the browser "firefox" is opened only the first time I run the test. 
Then each time I run the test, it fails with error  "execution expired (Timeout::Error)"

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, Ruby 1.8.7 , Rails 2.3.5.

gem list :

- capybara (1.1.2)
- cucumber (1.2.0)
- cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
- selenium-client (1.2.18)
- selenium-webdriver (2.21.1)
- webrat (0.7.3)

Comment: you must to provide your test code!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I don't know the reason but installing the gem launchy solved it.
Check it out if this is helpful
https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy